# How to get string url out of registered route in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In Global.asax we register routes using:

```
MapRoute(this System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes, 
    string name, 
    string url, 
    object defaults, 
    string[] namespaces)
```

Is there a way to retrieve the `string url` from code? Specifically, I am interested in getting route segments from the urls for registered routes like this:

```
"customRoutePrefix/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

I need to look up "customRoutePrefix" or the equivalent for any registered routes.

I thought I might be able to use `System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes` to do this, but I haven't found it in there.

Is this possible / how should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You can use:

```
this.RouteData.Values["segment name"]
```

For example,

```
this.RouteData.Values["controller"];
```

#### Edit 1

This piece of code will do the trick to retrieve all the registered routes URL's

```
var res = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in RouteTable.Routes)
{
    var r = (Route)item;

    res.Add(r.Url);
}

this.ViewBag.Res = res;
```

In your view:

```
@foreach (var item in this.ViewBag.Res)
{
    <div>@item</div>
}
```

Results:

```
Chapter14/{controller}/{action}/{id}
Movies/{controller}/{action}/{id}
api/{controller}/{id}
{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}
{resource}.svc/{*pathInfo}
{controller}/{action}/{id}
wcf/{*pathInfo}
```

Comment: For the case `"customUnknownPrefix/{controller}/{action}/{id}"` how would I access the first segment? In this case the value I'm looking for would be `"customUnknownPrefix"` but it could be anything that gets registered.

Comment: Well since that part is _not a part of the route values, instead it's a static segment_ probably your best shot is by inspecting the `this.Request.RawUrl` or `this.Request.Url.Segments`

Comment: It is part of the route Url that was defined when I registered the route using `MapRoute()`. My question is how I would get the list of all route urls from the registered routes. `this.Request.RawUrl` and `this.Request.Url.Segments` will only return values for the current url... not all of the registered routes. I need to be able to get this list of urls without a request.